# Do saturated fats cause heart diseases?

Tags: nutrition, disease

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are saturated fats unhealthy?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1231/are-saturated-fats-unhealthy)

Based on the answers posted on [this earlier question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1231/2016) and [the recent video](http://youtu.be/v8WA5wcaHp4) that I saw on youtube that claims that Fat does **NOT** cause heart diseases ([IMDB link](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1333994/) to the  documentary called [FatHead](http://www.fathead-movie.com/)), I do not know what to believe.

Moreover, this website is based on trusting peer-reviewed papers. If the credibility of such a widely-accept <s>fact</s> thing gets refuted, what should a person believe?

Comment: The first part of the question is clearly an exact duplicate.

The second part of the question is a philosophical question. What do we do when the best method we have for finding the truth takes time? We demand more research, we wait, we come to terms with the  fact that we are not yet omniscient, and we make decisions based on the most likely answer.