# Is fat as bad as we are led to believe?

Tags: medical-science, nutrition, obesity

According to [*Fat is back: Rediscover the delights of lard, dripping and suet* in *The Independent* (2009)](https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/food-and-drink/features/fat-is-back-rediscover-the-delights-of-lard-dripping-and-suet-1642912.html), the idea that eating a diet high in saturated fat clogs up the arteries and leads to heart disease is based on two weak reports; and the American National Heart, Lung and Blood Institute has found no link between diet and heart disease.  The report points out that

> In 2003, Professor Sylvan Lee Weinberg, a former president of the American College of Cardiology, said there was no longer any defence for a low-fat, high-carb diet. A 2008 report in the American Journal of Preventative Medicine actually pointed the finger at US dietary guidelines for the rise in obesity.

This could also point the finger at dietary guidelines here in the UK as I believe they are not that different to the US (if at all).

So what are the real facts? Are dietary guidelines flawed?  Can we safely go back to eating and cooking food highly flavoured by the juices rendered from the meat and other fats used in cooking?

Comment: There was a very similar question, but based on a slightly different article, a while ago - [Do high-fat diets causes heart disease?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/32423/do-high-fat-diets-causes-heart-disease). Also [Are saturated fats unhealthy?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1231/are-saturated-fats-unhealthy?rq=1) Do the answers to those answer your question?

Comment: [The title doesn't match the claim.]